# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation from the delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, rotation

in my application I have a background functions which caches data - works fine.
I have implemented  UIView *cacheProgressView; which is a visual indication to the progress of the caching mechanism. (it contains UIProgressBar and such)

Since I want to show this in all my application views (UINavigation with many views) I have added this to my delegate which take care of it rather well

```
[self.window addSubview:cacheProgressView];
```

**Problem is**: when I rotate the device and since cacheProgressView is attached to the window and not a view I can not set it to a proper position - the following function inside of the delegate is never called:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    NSLog(@"Rotation detected from the delegate");

    return YES;
}
```

how should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register for rotation notifications...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(didRotate:)
           name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];


- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification{  
  UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
  // do stuff
}
```